# Каким атрибутом можно отключить обтекание во время нажатия на поисковую форму?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="">главная</a></li>
 <li><a href="">красота & здоровье</a></li>
 <li><a href="">мода & стиль</a></li>
 <li><a href="">дом & быт</a></li>
 <li><a href="">отношения</a></li>
 <li><a href="">дети</a></li>
 <li><a href="">общество</a></li>
 <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Поисковая фраза...">
</ul>
```

Comment: Не нужно его отключать. Не для этого делали.

Comment: Я его округлил, но при наведении он становится прямоугольным. Есть способ округлить его тоже?

Comment: Вы про `outline`?

Comment: Nikita Umnov да

Answer (score 2):

Если вы о рамочке вокруг поля во время фокуса, то например так:

```css
input[type=search]:focus {
  outline: transparent;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="">главная</a></li>
 <li><a href="">красота & здоровье</a></li>
 <li><a href="">мода & стиль</a></li>
 <li><a href="">дом & быт</a></li>
 <li><a href="">отношения</a></li>
 <li><a href="">дети</a></li>
 <li><a href="">общество</a></li>
 <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Поисковая фраза...">
</ul>
```

Comment: Или `outline: none;`